# Struggling with building an intuition for recursion

Tags: recursion

Though I have studied and able am able to understand some programs in recursion, I am still not able to intuitively obtain a solution using recursion as I do easily using Iteration. Is there any course or track available in order to build an intuition for recursion? How can one master the concept of recursion?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to gain a thorough understanding of how recursion works, I highly recommend that you start with understanding [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), as the two are very closely related, if not arguably identical.

Recursion is a way of breaking down seemingly complicated problems into smaller bits. Consider the trivial example of the factorial function.

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

To calculate `factorial(100)`, for example, all you need is to calculate `factorial(99)` and multiply 100. This follows from the familiar definition of the factorial.

Here are some tips for coming up with a recursive solution:

- Assume you know the result returned by the immediately preceding recursive call (e.g. in calculating `factorial(100)`, assume you already know the value of `factorial(99)`. How do you go from there?)
- Consider the base case (i.e. when should the recursion come to a halt?)

The first bullet point might seem rather abstract, but all it means is this: a large portion of the work has already been done. How do you go from there to complete the task? In the case of the factorial, `factorial(99)` constituted this large portion of work. In many cases, you will find that identifying this portion of work simply amounts to examining the argument to the function (e.g. `n` in factorial), and assuming that you already have the answer to `func(n - 1)`.

Here's another example for concreteness. Let's say we want to reverse a string without using in-built functions. In using recursion, we might assume that `string[:-1]`, or the substring until the very last character, has already been reversed. Then, all that is needed is to put the last remaining character in the front. Using this inspiration, we might come up with the following recursive solution:

```py
def my_reverse(string):
    if not string: # base case: empty string
        return string # return empty string, nothing to reverse
    return string[-1] + my_reverse(string[:-1])
```

With all of this said, recursion is built on mathematical induction, and these two are inseparable ideas. In fact, one can easily prove that recursive algorithms work using induction. I highly recommend that you checkout this [lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/video-lectures/lecture-2-induction/).